# Seed is to sprout as

Tags: logical-deduction

I came across this question and couldn’t find an answer to it. The question goes like so:

Seed is to sprout as

A. Plant is to grow

B. Garden is to weed

C. Dawn is to morning

D. Teenager is to infant

E. Downpour is to trickle

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hello Henry! Can you provide a source for this riddle? If not, then I think this might not meet our Community Guidelines on Puzzling.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This question is off-topic for the site - it appears to be a standardized test question rather than a puzzle. Additionally, you need to give [proper attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) to questions you did not create yourself. Questions using someone else's content without attribution are generally [deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is C. The relation between Seed and Sprout is **Sprout is always the next phase of the Seed and irreversible**, so does the relation between dawn to morning.

For A, plant will grow or might be withered.
For B, garden is not necessary to weed.
For D, the direction is opposite, should be infant to teenager.
For E, trickle might to be downpour again.